# Inline ASM in C#

Tags: c#, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

does anyone have an idea about how can i convert the following C inline ASM to a valid C# format? Thanks in advance.

```
DWORD WINAPI RemoteExecPayloadStub(LPVOID lpParameter) {
__asm {
    mov eax, [lpParameter]
    call eax
    push 0
    call ExitThread
}
return 0;
```

}

EDIT

Tried to convert the ASM to bytecodes like so (below) and use it from a byte array but doesn't seem to work as expected. Thanks.

```
    0:  a1 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,ds:0x0
5:  ff d0                   call   eax
7:  6a 00                   push   0x0
9:  e8 fc ff ff ff          call   a <_main+0xa>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Can you show us your attempt?

Comment: Nothing to try here actually... You can't invoke ASM from C#. Some workarounds, like compiling c/c++ containing the asm code into library and calling from C# could work.

Comment: @EugeneSh. do you think there is a way arround this problem without having an extra DLL?

Comment: @SlothGR I don't think so.

Comment: NO, you know the compiled c# code runs under a VM rite, so standard assembly wont work

Comment: @EugeneSh. "nobody told him it was impossible so he did it" ... come on guys, just read the duplicate question!

Comment: @Jester So how does it contradict my comment?

Comment: In every possible way? It can be done quite simply. Especially this code which only invokes a function pointer. `Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer` is pretty much a drop-in replacement for this.

Comment: @Jester So, write a function in C, embed asm code in it, wrap into a library and call it from C#? And what did I say?

Comment: No you don't need to do that.

Comment: @Jester So you are talking about invoking this specific `ExitThread` function, not asm code in general?

Comment: @EugeneSh. yes, i am talking about this function only! Not in general! The ExitThread above!

Comment: Oh well, so just follow @Jester's link :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since people seem totally confused, I'll answer this here even though it is a duplicate.

The given code does nothing else but invoke a function pointer, and then exit the thread. As such the equivalent C# code could be:

```
delegate void FuncPtr();
static void RemoteExecPayloadStub(IntPtr lpParameter)
{
    FuncPtr ptr = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer<FuncPtr>(lpParameter);
    ptr();
}
```

As for the `ExitThread` you can use `Thread.CurrentThread.Abort()` or pinvoke the winapi function (not recommended).

Executing arbitrary machine code isn't much more difficult either. Put your stuff into a byte array, allocate executable memory using appropriate pinvoke calls, copy your code there and then use the above method to execute it.